# What is a better algorithm for finding routes that traverse all vertices in a graph?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

So I have the following problem:

> Given a grid of x by y dimensions, calculate the number of routes
>   through it that start in one corner (let's say top left) and end in
>   another (bottom right) and pass through every vertex.

So my current method just brute forces it by just trying every possible path and counting the ones that reach the finish and traverse every node. While it works, it's O(n^2) and gets unbelievably slow extremely quickly. I'm not sure how to do it combinatorially because of the requirement that the path traverse every vertex.

I've looked up more complex algorithms, and Hierholzer's algorithm for calculating Eulerian paths seems somewhat related but not perfect because nodes cannot be traversed more than once for this.

As it is, my program works, but badly, and I would like to make it more efficient. Are there better algorithms I could be using?

**Edit** Thanks for the answers so far. Just to clarify, all nodes in the 2d grid are connected by n/e/s/w

Also, the grid does not have to be a square

Comment: Isn't this the traveling salesman problem? If so, the person who answers it not only gets a few points, but also a Nobel prize!

Comment: If it "gets unbelievably slow extremely quickly" then it's not `O(n^2)`

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Yeah I think brute forcing this is factorial

Comment: @ccleve This is not the TSP.  TSP is when you're minimizing the total distance traveled, not simply counting the number of paths.

Comment: Look into any `Spanning Tree` algorithm

Comment: BTW, can you dump some numbers for small x? Maybe it's possible to do interpolation from them?

Comment: @hate-engine Good idea... OEIS: my favorite integer extrapolation engine, alongside WA and intuition :-)

Comment: After the edits, this is just a math problem with a final answer, should not need to use traversal/etc. Simply calculate by plugging in a value for x in an expression

Comment: @AK4749 migrate to [math.se], then?

Comment: @JanDvorak definitely. it's just a counting problem

Comment: Thanks. I posted this question on Mathematics here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274856/counting-the-number-of-paths-through-a-grid-graph-traversing-all-vertices-only-o). @AK4749, do you have a sense of what the expression would be? Also note I fixed a typo in the op, the grid can be of different x and y dimensions, does that change things?

Comment: Actually, it could dynamic programming here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), where should it belong?

Comment: @hate-engine Do you have a sense of dynamic methods that would help? I've fixed it so it won't traverse the "finish" node until every other node is traversed, and that cut off quite a bit of time but it's still fairly slow and I'm at a loss for what else to change.

Comment: The quoted problem places no restriction on the number of times a vertex may be visited, although it probably should. Without a restriction, the number of paths is infinite.

Comment: ^ good point. @CharmQuark, I, not being a math major, would use a technique of trying simpler values for x/y that I can count out by hand / use a computer for, find the pattern, and attempt to extrapolate to a final formula. Do you understand, though, why I say it's a mathematical problem rather than a programming one? However, I certainly agree that programming would make it easier. In addition to the migration, I think allowing it to stay here as well wouldn't hurt too much

Comment: I'm quite interested to see this answer haha

Comment: The solution seems fairly straightforward without the requirement that every vertex be visited exactly once: you can just use the binomial formula as shown [here](http://joaoff.com/2008/01/20/a-square-grid-path-problem/). The result could be established by taking (Number of total routes) and subtracting the number of routes that do not traverse every vertex. However I don't know how / if that can be calculated.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can do, because it's [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is NP-complete.

However, you *may* actually search for something else and add some restrictions to the problem you are trying to solve...

#### EDIT:

As @JanDvorak noted, *your specific restriction* is that your are using square grid. My findings so far:

If `x` is even, than there is no way to go through all vertices starting from top left corner and end in bottom right. Proof:

Lets count *directed* movements along axes, e.g. up is `-1`, down is `1`, left is `-1`, right `-1`. So, having x by x grid, your total movement would be `2*x`. At each vertex (except the last one!) your are selecting only one direction. So, if there is even number of vertices you need to go through, your total movement would be even and vice versa for odd. If `x` is even, than there is odd number of vertices, but total movement is stil even => you are not able to find any way.

Comment: You know the graph is a grid. Doesn't that simplify things a bit?

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes you are probably right, I'm thinking about it right now.

Comment: I see. In this case, the corners were just for example purposes (I'm looking for methods that work for any combination of 2 corners) but that definitely helps in the diagonal cases. What about in cases where the start and finish corners are on the same side?

Comment: @CharmQuark, well, you need to check, that "total movement" and number of passable vertices is same modulo 2 (e.g. division remainder is same). If that not in case => there is no paths for sure.

Comment: @JanDvorak, sure. BTW, there was a square grid in question. However, if OP could show some numbers, it *probably* may be easer to guess correct formula and prove it.

Comment: @hate-engine OP has just clarified it doesn't need to be a square-sized grid.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, "x by x" was a typo, I meant to write "x by y"

Comment: definitely harder, but still just a math problem. I suggest asking over at math.SE as @JanDvorak has suggested

Comment: shorter proof: color the grid like a chess board, and note that a path that visits an even number of grid squares must end on a square of opposite color.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with problems like this on a subject this semester. 
I think you could have a look on metaheuristic algorithms such us:

- [Tabu Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabu_search)
- [Evolutionary Computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation)

You might want to stay with brute force though, Unless you really need an improvement; because they are quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if x is even, there is a simple parity argument that shows the answer is always zero; chequer the grid and notice that the top-left and bottom-right squares are the same colour, and that colour cannot be visited both first and n<sup>2</sup>th since n<sup>2</sup> is even while 1 is odd.

If x is odd, I don't know how to count the paths, but notice that the total number grows at least exponentially quickly:  any traversal of an n*n grid can be lifted to two distinct traversals of an (n+2)*(n+2) grid.  You get one by going right along the top row, left along the second row, down along the first column, up along the second column, and then doing your n*n grid traversal on the remaining squares; you get the other by covering the first two rows and columns in the opposite order.

This should tell you that a brute-force solution is unlikely to work very well.