# What is the best way to count the number of Hamiltonian paths through a grid?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

So I'm trying to solve a problem regarding counting the number of paths through a grid. The problem is more or less as follows:

> Given a rectangular grid of x by y dimensions, calculate the number of paths from the top left to bottom left that visit every vertex exactly once

I have tried brute forcing the problem, but it seems to be O(n!) and is very slow with large dimensions.

My current method starts at the top left node and recursively checks every adjacent node that has not yet been visited, saving it to backPath list. If the function arrives at the finish and every node has been visited, it adds the backPath to a list of solutions to count the total number of paths.

However this is very slow. I understand there are dynamic ways of improving the algorithm, (including an article [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~wdtseng/icpc/notes/dp1.pdf)) but without much familiarity with dynamic programming / memoization I am having trouble figuring out how to implement improvements. The only improvement I've made so far is preventing the function from traversing the finish node before every other node has been visited, and this only trims the running time by about 40%. I don't have experience with DP and I haven't been able to really apply tutorials to my problem very effectively so far.

**Edit** I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248317/what-is-a-better-algorithm-for-finding-routes-that-traverse-all-vertices-in-a-gr) and the answers gave me better insight into what information I was actually looking for but I'm still stuck on how to apply DP / other running time reduction methods to this particular problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you repeating the question? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248317/what-is-a-better-algorithm-for-finding-routes-that-traverse-all-vertices-in-a-gr

Comment: @AdriánLópez I think that the answers presented in the other post suitably answer that question and to try and alter that question with the knowledge gained would then invalidate the entire initial question .. this question starts with the knowledge of the problem/complexity and is seeking optimizations within the bounds. They should indeed be linked (and even in the initial post), however. (And I would also suggest more research into those answers; this question was posted fairly hastily.)

Comment: You can always improve it to `O(n^2 * 2^n)` (for any graph, assuming each integer operation is `O(1)`) using Dynamic Programming. If this approach still interests you, let me know and I'll try to explain with more details.

Comment: First, if you want a quick boost in speed, simply increment a counter, instead of adding the solution to a list. Also, I have a couple ways to trim the tree to make recursion way faster, so let me know if you are still around, before I go into it.